# Do I need to Give Internet Permission to WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, asp.net-web-api

I made a web api and have now hosted it on windows azure. I see my links are working(through browser and fiddler).

However my windows phone 7 app(that I am running through Vs 2010 in the emulator) no longer can seem to connect to my webapi.

Do I need to set something to make it work?

**Edit**

I unistalled fiddler and now it works. It is something to do with fiddler. I would like to reinstall fiddler but not sure how to fix this problem.s

Comment: What if you run your wp app in debug mode? Anything?